# Change background colour of button after multiple buttons are clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, button, background-color

I am using Visual C# 2010

I have a windows form with about 24 buttons plus a 'Finish' button

Currently the Finish button is red. I want the colour of this button to change to green once all other buttons have been clicked.

When the user clicks button 1 -24 *that* button changes to green, so I know how to change the background  on a click event.

I have a boolean for when each button is clicked.

This is the code I have so far:

```
if (button1Clicked && button2Clicked ...)  // I have button3 through button24 as well
{
    finishButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

However the button remains Red when all 24 buttons have been clicked.
I have sent the output of button1 to the debug writeline and I know that the boolean changes from false to true when the button is clicked.
I have made the finish button public in the modifiers option.

Am I missing a step? I thought this should have been easy to accomplish.

EDIT

---

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public bool button1Clicked = false;
    .... // and other buttons are allocated the same way
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String textForClipboard = String.Format("{0}_S1_{1}", Form1.dateValue, button1.Text);
    Clipboard.SetText(textForClipboard);
    button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    button1Clicked = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(button1Clicked);
}
```

EDIT

---

Where exactly should I have the if loop?
I currently have it in this method

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        ....

        public Form2(Form parentForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainForm = parentform;
            ....

            if (button1Clicked)
            {
                finishedButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also show the code where `button1Clicked` is assigned a value?

Comment: @globetrotter code added

Comment: i was referring to when `button1Clicked` becomes `true`

Comment: `==` is used to check for a value, `=` is used to assign a value. try `finishButton.BackColor = Color.Green;`

Comment: are all your buttons named (not their text) `button1` to `button24`?

Comment: That's correct. The button text is a street name generated from a previous form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick'n'dirty solution, which however works. It assumes that your 24 buttons are named (not their text) `button1` to `button24`.

1) put your 24 buttons in a `GroupBox` (e.g. `groupBox1`)

2) put this in `partial class Form2 : Form`

```
bool[] allButtons = new bool[24];

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var indexButton = int.Parse((((Button)sender).Name.Substring(6))) - 1;
    allButtons[indexButton] = true;
    allButtonsClicked();
}

private void allButtonsClicked()
{
    const int totalButtons = 23;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalButtons; i++)
    {
        if (allButtons[i])
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == totalButtons)
    {
        finishButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

3) put this in `Form2_Load()`

```
foreach(Control ctl in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is Button)
        {
            ctl.Click += button_Click;
        }
    }
```

**What it does**:

It loops through all the controls in `groupBox1` when `Form2` loads, checks if they are `button`s and hooks all 24 buttons `click` events to `button_click()`. This way you don't need to declare 24 button clicks, since `button_click()` will trigger every time each of the 24 buttons is clicked.

We then have an `allButtons` `bool` array with 24 positions, all initially set to `false`. Each time `button_click()` triggers, we extract the "numerical" portion of the name of the button triggering `button_click()` at that given time (so for example if it's `button1` triggering `button_click()` at than given time, we take substring `"1"` from `"button1"`), convert that to an int (so `"1"` becomes `1`) and use that to set `allButtons[0] = true` (the array is zero-based, hence why `1` is used for index `0`). When all 24 elements of `allButtons` become `true` (which is checked in `allButtonsClicked()`), we change `finishButton`'s color to `Color.Green`.

Comment: You, my friend, are a scholar and a gentleman. This approach did exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: I really like how you explained what the code does. It makes the code easy to understand and helped me work out what was happening.

Comment: There's no point in using code you don't understand - a good solution should be accompanied by an even better explanation!

Answer (score 2):

A small modification to globetrotter's answer.
Change the `allButtonsClicked()` to return `bool` instead of `void`:

```
private bool allButtonsClicked()
{
    const int totalButtons = 23;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalButtons; i++)
    {
        if (allButtons[i])
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == totalButtons)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So you can then do:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var indexButton = int.Parse((((Button)sender).Name.Substring(6))) - 1;
    allButtons[indexButton] = true;
    if (allButtonsClicked())
    {
        finishButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

This just results in the code being more readable and understandable in every-day language: `"Whenever a button is clicked, check if each of the 24 buttons has been clicked at least once. If yes, then change the BackColor of finishButton to Green"` and centralises your logic in one place rather than two.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure that the inner part of the condition is executed anytime.
for example you can pop up a message box.
Check only for 3 buttons for first, smaller  test cases.

For other test, remove the whole condition and use only the color changing. Is this works?
If not, then you have to play around that part for first.

If it is works, then go back to your condition, that will be the leaker. Check for first only one button clicking. And then two etc.

In that way you can easily find your answer anytime. Do it in small tasks, to find the issue.

Tick a debug point to the condition, and check which flag is false. Mouse over button1clicked etc, all should be true

Comment: I have already tried those suggestions. The finish button changes colour when it is clicked, but not when the other buttons have been clicked.

Comment: Unfortunately that was just a typing mistake in my question. It only has one = sign in my code

Comment: Tick a debug point to the condition, and check which flag is false. Mouse over button1clicked etc, all should be true